# Form action URL error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form like this:

```
<?php
    echo form_open('/student/insert',array('name' => 'myform');
?>
// form data like label, input tags
// submit button
<?php 
     echo form_close();
?>
```

I have a URL which shows this form:

```
http://localhost/mycodeigniterproject/index.php/student
```

Now when I submit this form, the URL becomes:

```
http://localhost://mycodeigniterproject/index.php/mycodeigniter/controllers/index.php/student/insert
```

Whereas I expect it should be:

```
 http://localhost/mycodeigniterproject/index.php/student/insert
```

What is problem in my code? Why doesn't CodeIgniter use a relative path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the form from

```
echo form_open('/student/insert',array('name=>'myform');
```

to

```
echo form_open('student/insert',array('name'=>'myform');
```

This should do the trick.

**EDIT:**

Have a look [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html). You'll find an example of how the form helper works.

Comment: it doesn't work again. Now url become this

http://localhost://mycodeigniterproject/index.php/student/mycodeigniter/controllers/index.php/student/insert

Comment: What is the `base_url` in app/config/config.php ? Should be like : `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mycodeigniterproject/';`